# Why are pointers modified in a function ?

Tags: c++, function, dynamic-memory-allocation

As a beginner in C++, first thing I came accross for functions is that they use a copy of the argument, for example if we execute this :

```
void add (double x){
  x=x+3;
}

int main(){
double x=2 ; 
add(x) ;
}
```

Then x would actually be equal to 2, not 5. Later on, learning about pointers, I found the following :

```
void fill (int *t){
  for (int j=0, j<10, j++){
  t[j]=j;
}

int main(){
int* p;
p = new int[10];
fill(p);
}
```

Now if we print what p contains, we find that it's indeed filled by the integers. I have some trouble understanding why it does that as I feel like it should have been the same as the first function ?

Thanks.

Comment: The argument itself is *copied*, but when you *copy* a pointer, the copied pointer still points to the original object, which means that when you modify the object being pointed to, you will see the change reflected when dereferencing the original pointer as well. This is a common way of creating a function that can modify an existing object (although in modern C++ the use of raw pointers is discouraged, with references or STL smart pointers being preferred)

Comment: You still pass the pointer by values. You don't modify the argument `t` itself, you modify the data it points ***to***.

Comment: This kind of thing is much clearer if you give different variables different names. Saying "`x` would actually be equal to 2" isn't accurate; the `x` in `main` would be 2, but the `x` in `add` would be 5 (before it goes away).

Comment: A pointer is not an array. When you talk about what "`p` contains" you have to be very careful: `p` is a **pointer**, and it contains a memory address; nothing more. Your function `fill` treats that memory address as the first element in an array; that's okay, because that's what the code does, but `p` does not **contain** an array; it **points to** an array.

Comment: To get `add` to modify `x`, define the parameter as a reference (i.e. an alias): `void add (double& y){
   y=y+3;
}`

Comment: If you print `p`, `&p` or `&p[0]` you will notice they are all the same. When you write `new int[10]`, you are allocating 10 **successive** ints in memory and returning the adress of the first one. This is why you can write `t[j]` in your `fill()` function and it does modify the values.

Comment: In the second case, the pointer passed is not modified.   If the pointer passed is the address of the first element of an array with ten or more elements, elements of the array are assigned.     Just as in the first case, if the second function did something like `t = something()` (i.e. assigning the value passed)  the change would not be seen by the caller - since `t` itself is passed by value.

Comment: @OmarAflak -- `&p` is **not** the same as `p` or `&p[0]`. Try it.

Comment: The *pointer* gets copied, not the stuff it points to.

Comment: @PeteBecker Right sorry `&p` is the adress of the pointer ! My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it isn't the same as the first function is because you are passing the *pointer* by value. This means that if you modify the actual pointer, e.g by assigning to it, then it would only be in that state inside the function. The value that the pointer *points* to is still the original value, which will get modified since both copied pointers point to that same original value (don't forget notation of the form `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a + i)`, which does a dereference and is modifying the pointed value, not the pointer itself).

A small example that illustrates this would be the following (not accounting for memory leaks):

```
#include <iostream>

int test(int* x)
{
    int* y = new int{10};
    x = y;
    std::cout << "Inside function: " << *x << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    int* t = new int{5};
    std::cout << "Before function: " << *t << "\n";
    test(t);
    std::cout << "After function: " << *t << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In first example you are using ordinary variable. When passing normal variable to function, like this, the function creates its own copy of the variable (it has same value as it has when you passed it, but it was copied to different place in memory). That is standard behaviour.

In second example you are using pointer: we can say that it points to the place in memory, where values are stored. Few of the advantages of them:

1) If you want to spare memory, but need to use same value in different functions -> mostly appplies to bigger objects than double, like array in your example

2) If you need to change value of variable/array/object in different functions

But careful, in the second function you still created copy, but not of value, but pointer. So basically, the "new" pointer is different object, but it is pointing to the same place in memory, so when accessing the value (which you are doing with [j]), you are editing the same place in memory.

It is not that easy concept to grasp, especially with more dimentional arrays, but hope this helped a little. You can learn some more in tutorials or c++ docs, for example this is a good one: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointers-in-c-and-c-set-1-introduction-arithmetic-and-array/